# Is there a reason a ThreadPool thread could stall calling a COM method in another module?

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, com

I am loading a C# assembly via COM from unmanaged C++, the assembly calls back into unmanaged C++ through a callback interface. The C++ application uses a Windows message loop and STA.

Interfaces are defined in C#:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("...")]
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void Start(ICallback callback);
    void Stop();
}

[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[Guid("...")]
public interface ICallback
{
    void Message(string message);
}
```

In C++, an implementation of `ICallback` is provided, while `IMyInterface` is implemented in C#. It fires up a background loop that will periodically call back into C++ via the callback, then returns leaving the loop running:

```
[Guid("...")]
public class MyInterface : IMyInterface
{
    ICallback callback;
    public void Start(ICallback callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        CallCallback("Test 1");

        StartAsyncMethod(); //deliberately doesn't await. 
    }

    void CallCallback(string message)
    {
        Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        Console.WriteLine($"'{message}'. Thread - Background: {thread.IsBackground}, Thread Pool: {thread.IsThreadPoolThread}, Thread ID: {thread.ManagedThreadId}");
        callback.Message(message);
    }

    async Task StartAsyncMethod()
    {
       var i=2;
       while(true)
       {
          await Task.Delay(5000);
          CallCallback($"Test {i++}");
       }
    }
```

Everything works except that sometimes, calls to the callback method stall - the C# code sits on that line forever, the C++ method is never triggered.
It seems that calls from the `async` method are to blame so I added the logging of thread details, my program output is then like:

> 'Test 1'. Thread - Background: True, Thread Pool: False, Thread ID: 3

> 'Test 2'. Thread - Background: True, Thread Pool: True, Thread ID: 6

The call `callback.Message(message);` stalls associated with the second line above when called from the background loop. My real code is more complex but all callback calls made directly from `Start` work fine; the moment the background loop tried to callback the C# code stalls (and the C++ code carries on working fine it just never gets the callback).

Is it feasible that the thread-pool thread is somehow causing this? Clearly I'm using it to get access into an asyncronous C# paradigm but it is a long-lived `Task` running a program-life loop (which I've obviusly simplified greatly for this question). What could I try to resolve this because I'm pretty stuck at this point!

**Finer Detail**

The C++ application talks to other C++ applications via COM. Until it does that - or if I prevent it from doing so - my callbacks *are* successful. The messageloop is fairly standard:
MSG msg;

```
while (MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &sm_hShutdown, FALSE, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS) > WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0)
     {
          TranslateMessage(&msg);
          DispatchMessage(&msg);
     }
}
```

C++ uses `CGlobalInterfaceTable` and basic COM e.g. `CoCreateInstance(ClassGUID, nullptr, CLSCTX_SERVER, GUIDIMyInterface, &pI);` - nothing fancy at all.

In addition, another C# COM assembly uses the same basic principle but uses old-fashioned Threads and non-await TPL and that does not have this problem.

** Update **

So I have just tried this without any TPL type stuff

```
    public void Start(ICallback callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        CallCallback("Test 1");

        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                CallCallback("Thread Test");
            }
        });
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
```

Exact same issue... `CallCallback` stalls in the STA thread.

The hypothesis is that I'm calling back into COM from a different thread than owns the object, but creating a STA thread means I'm just using a `different` STA thread. Since this is a library with no entry-point, how *can* I use the calling thread to callback... that thread fires `Start` then disappears.

Comment: If the COM object is not free-threaded (and most aren't), then the code would need to marshal to a different apartment. Assuming the COM object is STA (most are), then ensure your STA thread is pumping and not blocked.

Comment: @StephenCleary as far as I can tell it should be - but something weird is going on possibly relating to the C++ app talking to other COM modules (my code works just fine _until_ that happens but this is getting too deep to post all the details). I am wondering if my C# code can 'capture' thread 3 and use that for all callbacks!

Comment: Assuming it's an STA, then you could use a separate STA thread.

Comment: @StephenCleary you've gone a bit beyond my understanding, could you elaborate on that - a link or an answer describing what you mean in more practical detail? As far as I know everything _is_ STA, C++ uses simple `CoInitialize(nullptr)` bog standard call to `CoCreateInterface` with `CLSCTX_SERVER` etc

Comment: With all what's involved, many things could fail in the details. You don't have a complete reproducing project do you?

Comment: @SimonMourier it would be tricky due to reliance on in-house libraries and the fact it's part of a bigger system. If I end up creating one to test I'll share, but for now any help is welcome! I was hoping someone would say "oh you've remembered X" or "you need to do Y in this sort of situation" ;)

Comment: Had an issue with C#. Somehow its classes can be blocking - even scheduling a background worker. Scheduled a background worker to wait for some info from C++ COM object that would come later - it caused the GUI to freeze completely. Perhaps your issue is related.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if you create it with `CoCreateInstance` (and not ` CoCreateInstance`) it's definitely STA. Interfacing with STA COM is special. I think, but I'm not sure, that this may work if you spin up an STA thread and go from there. Your best bet is to get a copy of Adam Nathan's book (.NET & COM, the Complete Interoperability Guide (or something like that) ). Everything is in there

Comment: Questions: Does it do the same if you use plain ThreadPool class instead of .NET's async/await/task mumbo jumbo? Have you tried to use ConfigureAwait(false) on .NET's tasks (depending on context this can cause deadlocks)? Are you sure there's no hidden exception? Apartment model objects can be accessed only from the thread on which they were created. Your ICallback and IMyInterface objects seem to belong to different apartments. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151020-00/?p=91321

Comment: Cheers @SimonMourier. I get the premise but this is all written in C++ context and I'm pretty sure the C++ side is OK (we've been using this code for a decade!) so what I don't understand is what I might _do_ in C#. I had thought .Net marshaled everything for me but if not, then how can I make sure the right STA is used in async/TPL code? For that matter how can I even find out which apartment is assocaited with which object?

Comment: @Mr.Boy: I meant your *C# code* would need an STA thread, and that thread needs to be pumping and not blocked.

Comment: @StephenCleary so I tested with an STA thread and added otes (see edit). But as I say there, STA means a new thread means a new apartment. How could I possibly get the 'entry' thread when `Start` fires up a new thread and exits?

Comment: @Mr.Boy: An STA thread needs to pump messages. When you have an STA thread owning the COM proxy, .NET should marshal calls for you automatically. I think. Now that Don Box gave up understanding COM/.NET, it's a sure thing that no one else does. Not fully.

Comment: @StephenCleary I _finally_ figured this out. In C++, `CMyInterface` was being created in the main thread, but `Start` was being called in response to an incoming COM call, i.e in a different thread. I hadn't realised that in _C#_ an `ICallback` object is auto-generated and _this_ is tied (somehow) to the calling C++ thread. _So_... this meant when the callback was called from C# it was trying to be called against the wrong C++ thread. My solution: add `IMyInterface::Configure(ICallback)` and call this from the main thread in C++, now the callback calls back to the main thread. Ugh!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the existing (decade old) C++ code should NOT be calling COM from multiple threads, right? It just happened, nobody happened to do anything that revealed this bug before!